# How can I solve "Video not available" when trying to embed a Youtube video on a web page with the Youtube API

Tags: javascript, video, youtube, video-streaming, html5-video

I am  developing a webpage which needs to allow users to search for a Youtube video and then play it modifying the starting and ending time. I accomplish this using the Youtube API itself.

**Problem:**
The issue is that for some videos, instead of showing the player, I get an error message being displayed saying *"Video unavailable. Watch on YouTube"* and it provides an option to watch the **same video ID** on the main Youtube site (where it plays fine with no issues).

I have searched for information on the topic and some suggest:

- It is because of the id containing non-alphanumeric characters.
- The video having licensed content.
- The website being run locally.
- The origin-policy not strict enough.

**What I've tried:**
The video with this id `3G6aOZvNoCo` is an example of a video with an alphanumeric id, no licensed content, no regional restrictions and still does not work. I have deployed my web on an AWS EC2 instance, I got my own certificates so to have https, I enforced the content-policy with no results.

Can anyone help? I am providing my JS code just in case it is useful:

```
// Get DOM elements
const startBtn = document.getElementById('start-btn');
const startField = document.getElementById('start-field');
const endBtn = document.getElementById('end-btn');
const endField = document.getElementById('end-field');
const resetBtn = document.getElementById('reset-btn');
const shorticBtn = document.getElementById('shortic-btn');
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
const uri = urlParams.get('uri');

// Declare variables
let player;
let songName;
let artist;
let startTime = 0;
let endTime = 0;
      var tag = document.createElement('script');
      tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
      var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

//when player is ready
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player-div', {
        height: '360',
        width: '640',
        videoId: uri,
        events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady
        }
    });
}

function onPlayerReady(event) {
    event.target.playVideo();
    const duration = player.getDuration();
    endField.value=endTime=duration;
    // Start button click
    startBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
        let tmp = player.getCurrentTime();
        if(tmp<=endTime) startField.value = startTime=tmp;
    });
    // End button click
    endBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
        let tmp = player.getCurrentTime();
        if(tmp>=startTime) endField.value = endTime=tmp;
    });
    // Start field change
    startField.addEventListener('change', () => {
        let tmp = startField.value;
        if(tmp<=endTime) startTime=tmp;
    });
    // End field change
    endField.addEventListener('change', () => {
        let tmp = endField.value;
        if(tmp>=startTime) endTime=tmp;
    });
    // Reset button click
    resetBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
        startTime = 0;
        startField.value = startTime;
        endTime = duration;
        endField.value = endTime;
    });
    // Shortic button click
    shorticBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
        const shorticURL = `lastSteps.html?uri=${uri}&starttime=${startTime}&endtime=${endTime}&name=${songName}&artist=${artist}`;
        window.location.href = shorticURL;
    });

    const iddle= () => {
        let currentPos = player.getCurrentTime();
        if(currentPos>=endTime || currentPos<startTime) player.seekTo(startTime);
    }
    setInterval(iddle,200);
}
```

Comment: I suspect the issue is that it's a **music video**. Even the online [embed player](https://www.youtube.com/embed/3G6aOZvNoCo/) does not work.

Comment: That is possible, given that it fails with many music videos. However, there are other music videos which work. For instance, there is this one: "YfD_leQKSNk". Also, there are non-musical videos that do not work: "fFPfHIOlKPM". That is a prank call. I need a way of, if not handle any video, at least filter the ones that are not embeddable so my users don't receive useless results on their searches.